# overriding/removing default fields on views

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

When the end user creates a view on contacts, they don't want some of the automatic fields displayed in the selected fields section. They want the title and contact owner alias selection removed from the default for all new views they created going forward.

How do I over-ride that setting?

the default fields are:

Name

Account Name

Title

Phone

Email

Contact Owner Alias.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a setting that will let you change the default fields selected from the edit screen of a list view. At best you can train users to start with an existing view, edit, then do a "Save As" to clone and modify an existing view.